# Basic login not working with ionic.io platform

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Platform's Auth service to register and login user. Signup works fine but while logging in, it calls neither the success function nor the error function. The console, however, shows the message ''Ionic User: loaded user".

```
Ionic.Auth.login('basic', {'remember': true}, details).then(
    function(loggeduser){
        console.log("logged in");
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $state.go('app.dashboard');
    }, function(error){
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        vm.showAlert('Invalid username or password.');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

After signing up the user, make sure that (1) you saved the user, and then (2), that this login code executes AFTER the user has been successfully saved.

EDIT:

```
  Ionic.Auth.signup(details).then(function(newUser) {
    user = Ionic.User.current();
    console.log('check here if auth',user.isAuthenticated());
    //Implement your login here
}, function(error) {
    console.log('failed');
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by save the user? When I login to ionic.io, I can see that the user is created.

Comment: When you register a user, it should be saved to the db (which it looks like it did). If you go ahead and try log-in for that user right now, if it works, then you should take my advice because it is a timing issue.

Comment: I have created a separate login form and tried logging in with the same username and password. It looks like the login is successful but it doesn't call the success function.

Comment: The user is not authenticated after signup. Implementing login inside signup results in a similar issue. It doesn't call the success function but shows 'Ionic User: loaded user' in the console.

Comment: Oh, man. That sucks. It's probably not your fault then, your code looks exactly as the docs show. I'd suggest going with some other authentication...

Comment: Seems to be a fault with ionic as it is still in beta. Have been going through trail and error for 2 days. No luck.